# scala/play - Make a File object from an uploaded file

Tags: file, scala, playframework, upload

I am using scala playframework. I am uploading a file. On the server side I am receiving the file successfully. I want to create a File object from it. How to do it?

Here is the code that I have written so far.

```
  request.body.file("dataFile").map(
    currentFile => {
      // How to make a FILE object from currentFile
      //Something like
      //val file: File = new File(currentFile)
    }
  )
```

Is it possible? If so then how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFileUpload) it should work this way:

```
  request.body.file("dataFile").map(
    currentFile => {
      // How to make a FILE object from currentFile
      import java.io.File
      val filename = currentFile.filename
      val contentType = currentFile.contentType
      val myFile = new File(s"/tmp/somepath/$filename")
      currentFile.ref.moveTo(myFile)
      //now "myFile" is an object of type "File".
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is "/tmp/somepath/"? Can i write "somepath" or should it be application specific?

Comment: Just enter the path where you want to store your file. It can be absolute (i.e. `c:\\myFiles\\test.txt` or `/myFiles/test.txt` depending on your OS) or relative (to your project directory). If you use `somepath.ext` it will create a file inside your project root directory.

Comment: I just saw that there were a few extra spaces in front of the dots. You might need to remove them.